# How to add an image url obtained from a controller in a codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a image url in stored in the database, i need extract this Url and do place image in the view, how i do this?

the code in controller

```
 $resultado = $this->Productos_model->GetLogo();
 foreach($resultado as $row){
     $a = $row->Logo;
 }
   echo $a;
```

this returns the image url.

Comment: how do you call the view? did you read: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the image result to view as follows

**controller code**

```
$resultado = $this->Productos_model->GetLogo();

//pass your result to view
$data = array('result' => $resultado);
$this->load->view('your-view-name',$data);
```

**view code**

```
<div>
  <?php if(resultado){ 
       foreach($resultado as $row){ ?>
      <img src="<?php echo base_url().$row->Logo; ?>" />
  <?php } } ?>
</div>
```

You can modify the code as per the styling and look and feel of the website.

I hope that helps you.